# DateTime Format Day of Year

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a format value for DateTime.ToString("") that will specify the day of the year in three digits?

For example:

- Jan 1, 2012 would be 001
- Feb 1, 2012 would be 032
- Dec 31, 2012 would be 366 (leap year)
- Dec 31, 2011 would be 365

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, you can use [DateTime.DayOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).ToString("000");

Your examples:

```
new DateTime(2012, 1, 1).DayOfYear.ToString("000");
new DateTime(2012, 2, 1).DayOfYear.ToString("000");
new DateTime(2012, 12, 31).DayOfYear.ToString("000");
new DateTime(2011, 12, 31).DayOfYear.ToString("000");
```

Answer (score 1):

No; that's not [listed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a way to allow users to give a format that could handle the day of the year and I came up with the following code.

```
public static string FormatDate(this DateTime date, string format)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    int numOfjs = 0;
    bool escaped = false;
    foreach (char c in format)
    {
        if (c == 'j' && !escaped)
        {
            numOfjs++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (c == 'j' && escaped)
            {
                builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);
            }

            if (numOfjs > 0)
            {
                var dayOfYearFormat = new string('0', Math.Min(3, numOfjs));
                builder.Append(date.DayOfYear.ToString(dayOfYearFormat));
            }

            numOfjs = 0;
            builder.Append(c);
        }

        escaped = c == '\\' && !escaped;
    }

    if (numOfjs > 0)
    {
        var dayOfYearFormat = new string('0', Math.Min(3, numOfjs));
        builder.Append(date.DayOfYear.ToString(dayOfYearFormat));
    }

    return date.ToString(builder.ToString());
}
```

This allows you to have a format that will replace consecutive un-delimited letter j's with the day of the year.  It will zero pad up to 3 digits based on the number of j's.  More than 3 consecutive j's act like just 3.

It basically rewrites the format to replace delimited j's with just a j, and consecutive j's with the day of the year.  It then passes this new format to `DateTime.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but if you absolutely, positively, have to do it in one line of code without access to the `DateTime.DayOfYear` function (like I had to do today):

```
int myDay = floor(Now() - Date(parseInt(Now().ToString("yyyy")), 1, 1)) + 1;
```

Comment: I'm curious what your use case is where you a) had to do it in a single line of code and b) without DayOfYear

Comment: User side scripting, MS Access style. Yeah sure, I could have gone in and added the function we didn't even realize existed when the script handler was written, but then we would have had to recompile and test and get the customer the new build and wasted so much more of our time and the customer's time for a use case that has never popped up in the decade or so the program's been around, but it's so much better if we can do it with the functions already provided.